# Issue using a ObservableCollection from a different window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

When the user wants to add a new Reminder, they click the add button on the mainWindow; and once they have added the data, it should display it in a listbox on the main window using an observable collection.

This brings up a new window which brings up options of, at the moment Date and message.

When the user has entered the data, Finish method is called.

The issue is, when the user has finished inputting the data on the new window, I add it to the reminder collection, but it doesn't update on the main window. I am wondering if is a datacontext issue and if I am even going about this the right way?

Thanks for the help.

Add Window:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class AddWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private MainWindow mainW;

        public AddWindow(MainWindow mW)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            mainW = mW;
            this.Show();

            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Finish(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mainW.Reminders.Add(new Remind(SelectedDate, Message));
            this.Close();
        }


        private DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.Today;

        public DateTime SelectedDate
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedDate;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != selectedDate)
                {
                    selectedDate = value;
                    RaisePropertyChange("SelectedDate");
                }
            }
        }


        private string message;

        public string Message
        {
            get
            {
                return message;
            }

            set
            {
                if (message != value)
                {
                    message = value;
                    RaisePropertyChange("Message");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void RaisePropertyChange(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add Xaml

```
<TextBox Name="Time" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="124,60,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115"/>
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="124,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115"/>
<TextBox  Text="{Binding Msg}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="58" Margin="123,93,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="144"/>
<Button Content="Finish" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="135,226,0,0" Click="Finish" />
```

MainWindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;

        }

        private ObservableCollection<Remind> reminders = new ObservableCollection<Remind>();

        public ObservableCollection<Remind> Reminders
        {
            get
            {
                return reminders;
            }
        }

        private void Add(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddWindow addWindow = new AddWindow(this);
        }
    }
```

Mainwindow Xaml:

```
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="About">
        <MenuItem Header="Info"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
<Button  Content="New" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="6,279,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81" Click="Add" />
<Button Content ="Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="87,279,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="79" />
<Button Content="Change" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="166,279,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="73" />
<ScrollViewer Name="Scroller" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="235" Margin="0,31,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="346">
    <ListBox ItemsSource= "{Binding Reminders}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Height="41" Width="293" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=dateT}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Msg}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>
</ScrollViewer>
<Separator HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="13" Margin="0,266,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="362"/>
```

Remind :

```
public class Remind : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public Remind(DateTime dt, string ms)
   {
      DateT = dt;
      Msg = ms;
   }

   private DateTime datet;

   public DateTime DateT
   {
      get
      {
         return datet;
      }
      set
      {
         if (datet != value)
         {
            datet = value;
            RaisePropertyChange("dateT");
         }
       }
   }

   private string msg;
   public string Msg
   {
      get
      {
        return msg;
      }
      set
      {
         if (msg != value)
         {
            msg = value;
            RaisePropertyChange("Msg");
         }
       }
   }


   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected void RaisePropertyChange(string name)
   {
      if (PropertyChanged != null)
      {
         PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change dateT to DateT in your main window

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DateT}"/>
```

and you are done.

Under the bottom line everthing with the datacontext was ok. Your the 2 wrong property names were missspelled.

Comment: Please update already existing answer instead of posting two separate answers. Since cumulative of both answers can be marked as answer and not an individual answer.

Comment: Mine was almost identical to yours. Except I did't implement INotifyProperyChanged (which isn't needed in this Scenario) and I named the property "dateT" instead of "DateT" because the ItemTemplate binds to "dateT". Usually public properties start with an uppercase letter. That's why I thing its better to rename that binding. There is nothing wrong with your Remind class.

Comment: Thats weird. Changed the name associated with the bindings to match the properties, and still not working. Guess i'll try again tomorrow, Thanks for the help.

Comment: You may want to download my test solution and compare it with yours: [link](http://download.michael-goericke.de/Reminder.zip)

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I created a small solution with your code and it just works fine. The main windows's list gets updated right after I click finish. The only small problem is you use the wrong binding in AddWindow to the message. You bind to "Msg" but it should be "Message" in the 3rd line above:

```
        <TextBox  Text="{Binding Message}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="58" Margin="123,93,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="144"/>
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work for mine, are you using mainW.Reminders.Add(new Remind(SelectedDate, Message)); to add to the collection? and how are you doing the datacontext?

Comment: Very strange. I'm running your code without any modification (except the one already mentioned). Of cource I needed to add the Remind class (which is only a small container holding dateT and Msg). Everything was fine with the DataContext.

Comment: Just an idea: do overwrite the datacontext in the XAML somehow? May be by setting the ScrollView's parent datacontext? I just put your code into a grid of the main window.

Comment: Added my version of the reminder class at the bottom, does it look ok?

Comment: Looked through my xaml again, mainwindow's was posted above, doesnt seem to be setting the data context anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Code looks fine but I can see one issue in it:

TextBox in `AddWindow` is binded with `Msg` but the corresponding property name in code behind is `Message`. So, textBox is never binded properly and hence new item is added in collection with `String.Empty` value for `Msg`.

```
<TextBox  Text="{Binding Msg}" <-- HERE. It should be Message.
```

However, it should still show a new object in collection on GUI with empty string and DateTime value set on AddWindow even in case of binding failure.

---

For updated Remind class in question:

One issue in XAML binding where you are binding with field instead of it's wrapper property.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=dateT}"/> <-- HERE, Path name should be DateT.
```

Comment: DataContext seems completely fine. Try correcting the misspelled property names as suggested in another answer.

Comment: Yeah. This should be `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DateT}"/>` instead of `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=dateT}"/>`. You need to bind with property, not with field.

Comment: Yea, was using wrong convention so changed everything around, but forgot to change some things. Would there be any other reason why it works for Gomi, but not i? with pretty much the same code?

Comment: It works for Gomi because he created `Remind` class himself and he must have spelled the property Name correct over there. But, with your actual code (of Remind class) it won't have work for sure.